# Extending Zend_Db

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I apologize if my title is a bit misleading and it turns out that it's some other class under `Zend_Db`.

I use the following method of extracting data from a MSSQL:

```
// $_config contains information about how to connect to my MSSQL server
$config = new Zend_Config($_config);
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
print_r($db->fetchAll($sql));
```

So far no problem and everything runs smooth :).

Now I need to run some more complex queries with multiple rowsets:

```
$sql2 = <<<EOD
  DECLARE @test INT
  SET @test = 42
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = @test

  SELECT col2 FROM table2 UNION 
  SELECT col3 FROM table2 

  SELECT * FROM table3
EOD;
print_r($db->fetchAll($sql2));
```

I hope you get the idea.

Using `$db->fetchAll($sql2);` will result in

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 10038 Attempt to initiate a new
>   SQL Server operation with results
>   pending. [10038] (severity 7)
>   [(null)]' in
>   \Sacp026a\sebamweb$\prod\includes\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:234

The following function will return all the correct rowsets:

```
function sqlquery_multiple($zdb, $sql) {
    $stmt = $zdb->query($sql);
    $rowsets = array();
    do {
      if ($stmt->columnCount() > 0) {
        $rowsets[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
    return $rowsets;
}
print_r(sqlquery_multiple($db, $sql2));
```

Now my big question is:
How do I extend `Zend_Db`, so I can implement and use the function above as `$db->fetchMulti($sql2);` instead of `sqlquery_multiple($db, $sql2)`?

Thanks in advance :)

NB: It's worth mentioning that I'm using the [ODBC-patch](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-905) in order to be able to fetch multiple rowsets in the first place.

Comment: Not sure about answer, but you definetly extend Zend_Db_Adapter, not Zend_Db ;)

Comment: I had a feeling that it wouldn't be `Zend_Db`.

Are you saying that it is definetly `Zend_Db_Adapter` or could it be something else? I have found some examples of extending `Zend_Db_Abstract` as well, but I'm not sure which one to start on :(.